# Arkanoid Collision Detection... Again

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, physics

I have read dozens of questions here on SO (and not only) regarding arkanoid collision detection, namely, moving circle collision against a stationery rectangle, but all of them ask how to detect a collision or how to detect which side of the rectangle the ball hits. My question is a bit different - it concerns the calculation of the new speed direction in case when the ball hits the ***angle*** of the rectangle.

For simplicity's sake let's assume that `Vx >= 0` and `Vy <= 0`, that is, the ball is coming from the below from the left upward and rightward and also suppose I know it's gonna hit the lower side of the rectangle. The green arrow shows the approximate direction of the ball and the blue dot shows the first point on the line containing the lower side of the rectangle that the ball hits. If that point lies strictly within the lower side of the rectangle then all is trivial - just change `Vy` to `-Vy`. However when that point lies outside the lower side it means that the first point of the rectangle that the ball will touch is going to be its lower-left corner, in which case I don't think that changing the `Vy` to `-Vy` is correct. I think that the new velocity angle must be dependent on the distance of the blue point to the corner. Also I think that not only `Vy` but also `Vx` must change (preserving, possibly, the length of the V vector).
[image: pic]

So, ***how do we calculate the new Vx and Vy when we hit an angle***? If you know any good links that address this question I'd be delighted to know them. Also note that I am more interested in the absolute *physical model* of this rather than easy-to-code optimized approximations. You can assume there is no rotation involved. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to bounce off a horizontal wall. Do you know how to bounce off a wall that is at some other angle?

When the circle hits the wall, it makes contact at a single point. That single point is all the circle "knows" about the wall; the location of that point gives you enough information to calculate the new **V**. When the circle hits the corner, it makes contact at a single point (i.e. the corner) so it bounces *just as if it hit a wall at that point*.

Is that enough to go on, or would you like some math? (And if so, how comfortable are you with vector algebra?)

Comment: I am pretty comfortable with vector algebra. I also know how to bounce off arbitrary wall, but I didn't understand which imaginary wall are you talking about - I mean, surely it is neither horizontal, nor vertical, is it? How to calculate the angle of that wall?

Comment: Is it maybe 45 degrees from horizontal?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Given a wall, you can deduce a point. Given a point, it's just as easy to deduce a wall. (ROT13 spoiler: Gur enqvhf sebz gur pragre bs gur pvepyr gb gur cbvag vf gur abezny bs gur jnyy.)

Comment: Or is it maybe the tangent of the ball at the point of the angle?

Comment: Well then I still am confused about your answer. As I understand you say that there exists a hypothetical wall going through the angle and I must bounce off that wall in order to get correct new Vx and Vy. Well then, which wall is that?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: yes, it is the tangent of the ball at the point.

Answer (score 1):

A simpliciation that is often made when modelling rock blocks in rock mechanics is to assume that the corner of the rectangle has a small radius. The calculation is then one of two curved surfaces contacting. This approach tends to give more consistent behaviour than modelling corners as right angles an so is preferred where consistent results are needed.